# How can a pFET act as a current source?

Tags: mosfet, pmos

[image: Summary]

I was just watching an online lecture from my professor, and I am confused with a rather silly question. It says here that the pFET can act as a current source because the current flows towards VDD. However, isn't that the source of the pFET that's tied to VDD? I thought the current flew from source to drain and not drain to source like an nFET?

Comment: Id is a function of Vgs if you ignore some second order effects. If Vgs is constant then Id is also constant and for pmos it supplies current to the load. Current flows from top to bottom in the image or from source to drain here.

Comment: The arrow points downwards. Where do you get the "towards VDD" from?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that for a P-channel MOSFET current *usually* flows from source to drain towards the lower potential, the source being connected to the higher potential, Vdd in this case.

I say "usually" because it is possible for a P-channel MOSFET to conduct current in the other direction through its channel, with the drain at a higher potential, but you have to take great care with the body-diode, which may prohibit this usage.

Your professor's allusion to current flowing towards Vdd could mean:

1. the drain is higher in potential than Vdd (not the case in the right-hand example in the picture you provided),
2. as BrianB suggests, he/she was referring to the direction of electron movement, or
3. he/she mis-spoke, and meant to say "current flows from Vdd [towards ground, or some other lower potential]".

Comment: We're talking about semiconductors here, so he probably was referring to electron flow, which would flow towards Vdd from ground.

Comment: @BrianB that was my thought.  https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/which-way-does-current-really-flow

Comment: @BrianB, but we're talking specifically about a p-channel MOSFET, where the relevant carriers are positively charged. If the instructor wanted to bring electron current into this discussion, they were screwing up their students all kinds of ways.